# Replacing Meade ETX with computerized mount

Tags: telescope, refractor-telescope

I've been using a Meade ETX 90 for a few years now. Since it doesn't have the new computerized mount (with goto), I am looking into buying one to swap out. Where might I find this and is there a more technical term than just "computerized mount" that is used?

**Note**: This is an old scope that did not originally come with the ports that the autostar controller now goes into (on the newer models).

**Update**: I ended up getting a newer Meade ETX and plan to replace my current mount with the computerized one. Also, if you check out cloudynights.com you might be able to find one. I have seen one on there before.

Comment: Surely the ETX90 had a computerised mount from the start?

Comment: It’s an older scope. Like early 2000s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meade make the 497 auto star hand controller, which plugs in where your existing hand controller goes. This turns your mount into a fully computerised one. Alternatively you should be able to use a laptop to control the mount via the aux ports. It’s all in the manual.

If your telescope did not originally come with the auto star hand controller, here is a quote from [weasner.com](http://weasner.com/etx/faq.html#upgrade):

> **Q. How do I upgrade a non-AutoStar ETX to an AutoStar capable ETX?**
>
> Short answer: you can't. Meade does not offer an upgrade for the
>   original model ETX (also known as the ETX-90RA or ETX Astro M). But
>   you can mount the OTA on a different mount (see the Telescope Tech
>   Tips page) or (if still available) get a JMI computer system (see the
>   "NGC-microMAX/NGC-MAX" on the Accessory Reviews - Miscellaneous page).
>   Or you could sell it and by a new AT model.

Comment: Unfortunately, my scope is so old that the mount doesn't even have the ports that the star hand controller is supposed to plug into. I was wondering if Meade is actually known to sell this part of the scope individually. I was thinking about keeping the optical tube and replacing the actual mount that takes care of the slewing.

Comment: Is the hand controller hardwired into the base?

Comment: Check out this site:  http://weasner.com/etx/menu.html

Comment: This answered my question. I will update your answer with the relevant information. Thanks!